# Built-in OCR in macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, monterey, ocr, live-text

Recently I've found on my Mac that I can easily highlight text in an image that wasn't possible before.

Is there also a built-in CLI option or an AppleScript option to address the OCR program with which I can achieve the same results as tesseract?

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/interact-with-text-in-a-photo-prvw625a5b2c/mac

Comment: This ocr is called live text. It was released with monterey

Answer (score 20):

Shortcuts.app has an "Extract Text from Image" action.

[image]

There's also a shell command `shortcuts` to run a Shortcut.

Comment: Shortcuts seems to only be for iOS though not macOS, right?

Comment: @mowwwalker No, Shortcuts.app is in macOS, as of Monterey.

Comment: Sadly, I don't see it in the Shortcuts Gallery in 13.6.1 (22G313) .. is it no longer available??

Comment: @TryTryAgain Not in the Gallery -- Create a new Shortcut, and add it from the list of actions.

Comment: @benwiggy ... amazing, thank you for that clarification, I didn't realize you can create/add like that, I thought it was all via importing from what was available in the gallery. Thanks so much for the response, cheers!

Comment: Hmm, it appears to not really function. I added a shortcut but when pressing play it does nothing. I'm trying to extract text from an image that I have open in Preview (often it works within preview somehow, but occasionally it does not). I was hoping to be able to use something as a backup. How would I use the shortcut? I tried adding it to the dock too, it appears to do absolutely nothing when I click it or play it.

Comment: @TryTryAgain Probably best to read up on Apple's help pages for how Shortcuts work. You have to construct a workflow, with an input, an action and an output.

Comment: This seems promising ;) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZVlifUpr_c

Answer (score 5):

This is core of a simple cli tool to extract text from an image:

```
 let img = NSImage(byReferencing: url)
    guard let imgRef = img.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil) else {
        fputs("Error: failed to convert NSImage to CGImage for '\(url)'\n", stderr)
        return 1
    }

    let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest { (request, error) in
        let observations = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] ?? []
        let obs : [String] = observations.map { $0.topCandidates(1).first?.string ?? ""}
        try? obs.joined(separator: "\n").write(to: url.appendingPathExtension("md"), atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

        fputs("got page obs is \(obs)", stderr)
    }
    request.recognitionLevel = VNRequestTextRecognitionLevel.accurate // or .fast
    request.usesLanguageCorrection = true
    request.revision = VNRecognizeTextRequestRevision2
    request.recognitionLanguages = ["de"]
    request.customWords = ["more", "Worte", "Wort"]

    try? VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: imgRef, options: [:]).perform([request])
```

from this [full working project](https://github.com/MatthiasWinkelmann/macocr/blob/main/Sources/macocr/Runner.swift)

Comment: how are we supposed to use that? I tried pasting it in terminal but nothing happened

Comment: ^ this is a lovely script, nicely indented and everything - but @yarns -> please don't paste random code you find online into your terminal. the OP is probably a lovely, unstanding member of the community - but...

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps for a shortcut that lets you drag your mouse over an image and receive the text on your clipboard -- basically, copy and paste text from anything on your screen, including other people's screen shares!

#### Creating the shortcut

- Open the Shortcuts app and start a new shortcut.
- Add Action: Take Screenshot, set to Interactive, Show More, Custom.
- Add Action: Extract Text from [Screenshot] (the brackets fill in automatically)
- Add Action: Copy [Text from image] to Clipboard
- Add a title by clicking in the title bar: "Extract text from screenshot".

#### Adding your shortcut to the Dock

Go back to the main window, right click the shortcut, Add to Dock.

#### (Optional) Adding a beep when the clipboard is ready

- Find a sound in /System/Library/Sounds and drag it to the top. I used `/System/Library/Sounds/Basso.aiff`.
- Add Action: Play Sound. Show more, choose Select variable from dropdown. The top of the screen will say "Select a Magic Variable" and the word "File" will appear below the sound you added. Click that.
  (The dropdown will still appear blank, and there will not be a line connecting this action to the others -- that's OK.)

#### (Optional) Assigning a keyboard shortcut

Open Details (click `i` on the right hand side). Note that the shortcut takes a second to run after its icon appears in the top menu bar.

I have found this shortcut sometimes stops working, in which case I have had to close Shortcuts completely, find the keyboard shortcut in `System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services > Shortcuts`, then click into it and reassign it.

#### Screenshot of your new shortcut

[image: image of ocr shortcut]

Comment: could you please share this shortcuts and paste the url here? Thanks

Comment: I can't because my work computer blocks iCloud, but if you follow the directions you could share your link for everyone else.

Comment: Great post.  Very helpful!

Comment: Am tempted to share the shortcut. i can't see any security concerns - he mumbled as the virus coursed through his cyber neuron network – but I probably still would not run a publicly posted shortcut on my machine. Besides - it's much more fun making one yourself. AND! you get to watch your hard disc get wiped in real time :)